# How can I capture the url clicked?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've got a server that loads an html page by echoing the result of a function *file_get_contents* to an URL. I want to get the URL that is clicked by the user after this. I've tried:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');

echo $result;

echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
  "Event.observe(document.body, 'click', function(event) {",
  'alert("hi");',
  '});</script>';
```

But I don't know why it doesn't work!

Thank you

Comment: have you included a JS framework with the Event class? That looks like prototype JS. If it's not included, it won't work.

Comment: No, I haven't. There's any other way of doing that?

Comment: Do you know anything about Javascript? Event handling? I suggest learning, you won't get very far with copy-pasted code you do not understand.

Comment: Why do you say that? I do understand it

Comment: The only thing is that I didn't know the prototype framework

Comment: @Kits89 If you know how to properly attach an event handler, what is this question about? You certainly copy-pasted that `Event.observe()` from somewhere without knowing what that is.

Comment: I know how to attach an event handler because I've used the methods addEventListener for and add-on in FF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want a script that looks like this:

```
(function() {
  function onclick(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (target.tagName && target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
      alert(target.href);
    }
  }

  if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', onclick, false);
  } else if (document.body.attachEvent) {
    document.body.attachEvent('onclick', onclick);
  }
})();
```

This will work in IE and other browsers without using any JS libraries.

Answer (score 3):

a suggestion, using event delegation:

```
(function()
{
    function callback(e)//IE doesn't pass event object, but we'll fix that
    {
        var target;
        e = e || window.event;//get IE event
        target = e.target || e.srcElement;//IE again
        if (target.tagName !== 'A')
        {
            return true;
        }
        //a link has been clicked, target holds a reference to that link, e is the click event
        alert(target.href);
        //to prevent the link to be followed:
        if (e.preventDefault)
        {// all major browsers, except for ie
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }//now IE again:
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        return false;//not required to return here
    }

    if (document.body.addEventListener)
    {
        document.body.addEventListener('click',callback,false);
    }
    else
    {
        document.body.attachEvent('onclick',callback);//for IE > 9
    }
})();
```

This way, you only bind 1 event listener, to 1 handler, and it deals with all links that are clicked anywhere on your page. If you only want to block/handle certain links, you could give them a distinct class, and edit the callback function like so:

```
if(target.tagName !== 'A')
//add extra check:
if (target.tagName !== 'A' && target.className !== 'handleThisLinkClass')
```

google JavaScript event delegation, it's a really useful feature, especially when dealing with a large collection of elements that need event handlers

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler to understand, but this method uses JQuery, which is often included in many frameworks or cmses.

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        alert(this.href);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should unbind a click events so that your events will start to work.

```
<?php
        $result = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
        echo $result;

        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>';
        echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).unbind("click").click(function(){ alert("Hi!"); });
            // similarly
            $("a").unbind("click").click(function(){ alert($(this).attr("href")); return false; });
        });
        </script>';
?>
```